# Google adwords conversion on phone call?

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-ads-api, phone-call

I want to track adwords conversions when a user clicks on a phone number on my page coming from a google search. That's what i did:

I added a piece of script based on detectmobilebrowser.js to check if the user is using a mobile. you can see my script [here](http://www.servimulti.com/detectmobilebrowser.js)

I have a link on a phone number like this:

```
<a onclick='clickNumber()' href="tel:9xxxxxxxx">xxx xxx xxx</a>
```

And this is the javascript triggered when someone clicks on the number (notice that the conversion is only tracked if the click comes from a mobile browser):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function trackConv(google_conversion_id,google_conversion_label) {
         var image = new Image(1,1); 
         image.src = "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/"+google_conversion_id+"/?label="+google_conversion_label+"&script=0";      }
function clickNumber() {
    if(isMobile) {
        trackConv(xxxxxxxxxx,"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        }
}
</script>
```

The conversion is tracked when someone clicks on the phone number, but then they have to accept to call that number. How can I know when someone is actually making the phone call. Is ther any kind of API or event for such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there really is no way of knowing whether or not the call was actually placed (instead of the user merely clicking the link).

The best you could possibly do would require you to have a way of programatically know the time of incoming calls, and match up the time of the click with the time of the call. But this is far from a straightforward solution to do it in any kind of automated fashion.

The only other thing you could do is if you keep track yourself of when that linked is clicked, and present the person answering the call with a list of recent 'clickers', you'd then be able to do things like track call conversions against the number of 'successful' call conversions (assuming you're selling a product/service here)

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought... I suppose neither android nor ios provide an API to deal with it for security reasons...yet.

Comment: Indeed. Generally speaking it'd be bad for apps to know whether or not a phone call is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

I found it you can now track mobile call conversions, you need to set up properly google adwords and it will generate a special conversion code snippet that you'll have to place just before the body end tag.

To trigger the conversion when someone calls, don't forget to call `goog_report_conversion()` (which is defined in the code snippet provided) when someone clicks on the telf. You can do it like this:

```
<a onClick="goog_report_conversion()" href="tel: xxxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using their new Conversion Import feature (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en) in conjunction with a call tracking provider, it's possible to register any offline event as a conversion within AdWords.

When it launched in September 2013, I recall the blog post included a reference to Mongoose Metrics (call tracking provider) who had a whitepaper or something on how to make this work.